# Is there a site that lists Xbox 360 FPS with offline co-op mode?

Tags: xbox-360, first-person-shooter

I will buy a XBOX 360 FPS game for my brother for Christmas. Because we play oft together, I would like to buy a FPS which supports co-op offline playing.
We have had a lot of fun with COD MW2, COD World At War (a little bit frustrating that it didn't save our progress in co-op mode though).

I am looking into a series of lists, but the problem is that they always consider online co-op, which is not what we want.

Do you know any lists of Xbox 360 FPS games with offline co-op mode?

Comment: This is also called "couch co-op" which might be a good search term when you're looking around the internet.  Also, take a look at the Halo series, and if you can deal with third-person shooters, try Saints Row 2 & Saints Row: The Third, which I think both support local multiplayer and are very, very fun games.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you check out http://www.Co-Optimus.com, it has an extensive catalogue of games by co-op features, and you can filter by online/offline, genre, etc.

[This](http://www.co-optimus.com/system/1/xbox-360.html) is their X360 section

Comment: You beat me to it! ;)